# Вопрос по выборке из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно получить сумму из 10 строк, для этого пробую использовать следующий запрос:

```
SELECT SUM(hosts) FROM traffic LIMIT 10
```

Получаю почему то муссу всех записей...

Как можно получить сумму только из 10 записей?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
SELECT SUM(hosts) FROM (SELECT * FROM traffic LIMIT 10) AS tables
```

Answer (score 0):

1. задавайте ограничение кол-ва строк в части where:

SELECT SUM(hosts) FROM traffic WHERE условие на отбор 10 строк

2. через подзапрос

SELECT SUM(hosts) FROM (SELECT hosts FROM traffic ORDER BY `поле, по которому сортировка` LIMIT 10 ) t

Comment: Проблема как раз в том нужно без WHERE, второй вариант с под запросов то что надо, ORDER BY само собой. Большое спасибо что подсказали!